# Fixing the ordering of my bar plot and displaying values on top of (and within) bars

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have the following data and code that produces a bar plot.

```
#create data frame for bar plot
Correlation_task_persistence <- c("0.45", "0.40", "-0.46", "-0.24", "0.06", "0.16")
Biv_A_task_persistence <- c("63%", "66%", "67%", "71%", "69%", "55%")
Biv_E_task_persistence  <- c("37%", "34%", "33%", "29%", "31%", "45%")
Correlation_activity <- c("0.40", "0.33", "-0.59", "-0.10", "0.06", "0.10")
Biv_A_activity <- c("55%", "40%", "65%", "70%", "97%", "40%")
Biv_E_activity <- c("45%", "60", "35%", "30%", "3%", "60%")
age <- c("36", "30", "24", "18", "12", "6")
df.new <- data.frame(Correlation_task_persistence, Biv_A_task_persistence,Biv_E_task_persistence, Correlation_activity, Biv_A_activity, Biv_E_activity, age )

#produce bar pot
suppressWarnings(
  df.new %>% 
    mutate(across(Correlation_task_persistence:Biv_E_activity, 
                  ~if_else(as.numeric(gsub("%", "", .x)) > 1,
                           as.numeric(gsub("%", "", .x, fixed = TRUE))/100, 
                           as.numeric(.x)))) %>% 
    pivot_longer(-c(age, contains("Correlation"))) %>% 
    mutate(Correlation = if_else(grepl("task", name),
                                 Correlation_task_persistence, Correlation_activity),
           final_value = Correlation * value,
           name = gsub("_task", "", name)) %>% 
    tidyr::extract("name", c("var","group"), regex = "(.*)_([^_]+)$") %>% 
 ggplot(aes(x = age, y = final_value, fill = var)) +
  geom_col() +
   scale_fill_grey(
  start = 0.475,
  end = 0.8,
  na.value = "red",
  aesthetics = "fill"
  ) +
  labs(x="Age (months)", y= "Correlation") +
  facet_wrap(~group)
)
```

[image]

I would like to modify my code to make three changes to the bar plot:

1. Order the ages such that age 6 goes before age 12. So the order of the bars should go 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36. Instead of 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 6.
2. Display the correlation at the top of each bar (example in black for age 6).
3. Display the Biv_A and Biv_E value within the bars (example in black for age 6).

Would appreciate any help on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you're looking for, though it looks a little messy with all those text labels...

```r
df.new %>% 
  mutate(across(Correlation_task_persistence:Biv_E_activity, 
                ~if_else(as.numeric(gsub("%", "", .x)) > 1,
                         as.numeric(gsub("%", "", .x, fixed = TRUE))/100, 
                         as.numeric(.x)))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(age, contains("Correlation"))) %>% 
  mutate(Correlation = if_else(grepl("task", name),
                               Correlation_task_persistence, 
                               Correlation_activity),
         final_value = Correlation * value,
         name = gsub("_task", "", name),
         age = as.numeric(age)) %>%
  tidyr::extract("name", c("var","group"), regex = "(.*)_([^_]+)$") %>%
  group_by(age, group) %>%
  mutate(label = scales::percent(final_value / sum(final_value))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = age, y = final_value, fill = var)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = Correlation, group = age), 
            stat = 'summary', fun = function(x) sum(x) + 0.05 * sign(x)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = label), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_grey(start = 0.475, end = 0.8, na.value = "red") +
  labs(y = "Correlation") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = as.numeric(unique(df.new$age))) +
  facet_wrap(~group)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. How would I modify the font size of those text labels? Also, is there a way to modify the distance between the correlation label and the bar?

Comment: @ericm yes, text size is controlled by the `size` parameter inside `geom_text`. The distance from the top of the bar is controlled in this code by `0.05 * sign(x)`. Just change the 0.05 to whatever you wish. If you use the search bar at the top of this page you will find many, many Q&As related to text in ggplot.